# JQuery mutiple Button on click show different on output

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, kendo-ui-window

```
<div class="btn-toolbar">
<button type="button1" class="btn btn-primary btn mr-3" >Add Recyclable</button>
<button id="edit" type="button2" class="btn btn-secondary btn mr-3" disabled>Edit Recyclable</button>
<button type="button3" class="btn btn-primary custom btn mr-3">Add Type</button>
<button id="delete" type="button4" class="btn btn-danger custom"  disabled>Delete</button>
```

```
<div id="windowForAssign"></div>
<script>
$('button').click(createAndShowPopup);
var kendoWindowAssign = $("#windowForAssign");
var title = "Test";
var url = ""
function createAndShowPopup(){                              
kendoWindowAssign.kendoWindow({
width: "650px",
modal: true,
height: '500px',
iframe: true,
resizable: false,
title: title,
content: "test.html",
visible: false,
});
   
var popup = $("#windowForAssign").data('kendoWindow');
popup.open();
popup.center();
}
</script>
```

however as mention the button is classified as all button
how can i indicate that each button it do different pop up
like title and content ?
Example of pop up with different clicks
[example of how it look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5kDf.png)

if i change to $("button2").click ...
it wouldnt work as i wan to seperate them how can i do ?

Comment: could you explain what you want ot achieve ?

Comment: Hi, i want to show different click on the button

for example Add 
title is add recycables pop out 

Edit is Edit Recycables pop out 

Add type is Add type out 

Delete is just delete pop out

Comment: specify Id on each button and assign new click function !

Comment: how can i do it as i am pretty new to jquery still as i have already specify id on each buttons already

Comment: for edit use `$('#edit').click(...)` and delete  `$('#edit').click(...)` apply same for other buttons

Comment: U mean that for 
the button i should delete or u mean others ?

because i need the other buttons as well 
4 type of different buttons

oh thanks it working now for edit let me try the others with this type of function

Comment: no I meant the code for the delete button etc for others , not deleting the button it self

Comment: okay u mean all 4 button to have the same id is it ?

Comment: hi i manage to got it already
button link each on click on different content with some button and id changes 

Thankss